# Hibernate EnumType instantiation exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 4 and xml based mapping. Here is the exception I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate custom type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.byClass(TypeFactory.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.heuristicType(TypeResolver.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.setParameterValues(EnumType.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectParameters(TypeFactory.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:189)
    ... 53 more
```

And here is the enum mapping that I'm using

```
<property name="coachingStatus" column="status" update="true" insert="true" index="true">
      <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">com.tutorial.enums.CoachingStatus</param>
        <param name="type">12</param>
      </type>
    </property>
```

And here is the enum:

```
public enum CoachingStatus {
  ACTIVE, BLOCKED, PENDING, EXPIRED
}
```

here is the entity

```
public class Coaching implements Serializable {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Long locationId;
  private Integer organisationId;
  private Long ownerId;
  private Date createdOn;
  private Date modifiedOn;
  private CoachingStatus coachingStatus;
  private Long createdBy;
  private Long modifiedBy;
  private String email;
  private String logo;
  private String about;
  private String phone;
... //getters and setters
}
```

I checked out tutorial from here - [here](http://blog.javachap.com/index.php/enumeration-mapping-in-hibernate/) but I'm getting above error. Need help with this.

Comment: Do you have `CoachingStatus status` variable declared in Entity for this `hbm.xml` file

Comment: Yes. I'll add the entity also in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had same problem and it looks like the solution is to add another parameter. That way it won't try to persist it as ordinal but as string so I guess that string works better with VARCHAR type.

```
 <property name="coachingStatus" column="status" update="true" insert="true" index="true">
    <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
       <param name="enumClass">com.tutorial.enums.CoachingStatus</param>
       <param name="type">12</param>
       <param name="useNamed">true</param>
  </type>
</property>
```

by setting `useNamed` to `true` hibernate will store enum by using it's name so your data will not break if you change order in your enum type.