# Hibernate mapping between PostgreSQL enum and Java enum

Tags: java, postgresql, enums, annotations, hibernate-mapping

### Background

- Spring 3.x, JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.x, Postgresql 9.x.
- Working on a Hibernate mapped class with an enum property that I want to map to a Postgresql enum.

### Problem

Querying with a where clause on the enum column throws an exception.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
... 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: movedirection = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

### Code (heavily simplified)

SQL:

```
create type movedirection as enum (
    'FORWARD', 'LEFT'
);

CREATE TABLE move
(
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    directiontomove movedirection NOT NULL
);
```

Hibernate mapped class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "move")
public class Move {

    public enum Direction {
        FORWARD, LEFT;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequenceGenerator", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "move_id_seq")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "directiontomove", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Direction directionToMove;
    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

Java that calls the query:

```
public List<Move> getMoves(Direction directionToMove) {
    return (List<Direction>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .getNamedQuery("getAllMoves")
            .setParameter("directionToMove", directionToMove)
            .list();
}
```

Hibernate xml query:

```
<query name="getAllMoves">
    <![CDATA[
        select move from Move move
        where directiontomove = :directionToMove
    ]]>
</query>
```

### Troubleshooting

- Querying by `id` instead of the enum works as expected.
- Java without database interaction works fine:

  ```
  public List<Move> getMoves(Direction directionToMove) {
      List<Move> moves = new ArrayList<>();
      Move move1 = new Move();
      move1.setDirection(directionToMove);
      moves.add(move1);
      return moves;
  }
  ```
- `createQuery` instead of having the query in XML, similar to the `findByRating` example in [Apache's JPA and Enums via @Enumerated documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html) gave the same exception.
- Querying in psql with `select * from move where direction = 'LEFT';` works as expected.
- **Hardcoding `where direction = 'FORWARD'` in the query in the XML works.**
- `.setParameter("direction", direction.name())` does not, same with `.setString()` and `.setText()`, exception changes to:

  ```
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: movedirection = character varying
  ```

### Attempts at resolution

- Custom `UserType` as suggested by this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594020/1090474 along with:

  ```
  @Column(name = "direction", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // tried with and without this line
  @Type(type = "full.path.to.HibernateMoveDirectionUserType")
  private Direction directionToMove;
  ```
- Mapping with Hibernate's `EnumType` as suggested by a higher rated but not accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604286/1090474 from the same question as above, along with:

  ```
  @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.EnumType",
      parameters = {
              @Parameter(name  = "enumClass", value = "full.path.to.Move$Direction"),
              @Parameter(name = "type", value = "12"),
              @Parameter(name = "useNamed", value = "true")
      })
  ```

  With and without the two second parameters, after seeing https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241410/1090474
- Tried annotating the getter and setter like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20252215/1090474.
- Haven't tried `EnumType.ORDINAL` because I want to stick with `EnumType.STRING`, which is less brittle and more flexible.

### Other notes

A JPA 2.1 Type Converter shouldn't be necessary, but isn't an option regardless, since I'm on JPA 2.0 for now.

Comment: This is a very well written question. I wish more questions would clearly state the problem, show relevant code, and show attempts at resolution. Well done.

Comment: As of 14 Feb 2017, @cslotty's link is dead.

Comment: I second Todd's comment and will also add a helpful link to medium where I got my solution from: https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/how-to-map-java-enum-to-postgresql-enum-type-fcb3f81a7c42. There I didn't need to add Hypersistence Util, but only a `package-info.java`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### HQL

Aliasing correctly and using the *qualified property name* was the first part of the solution.

```
<query name="getAllMoves">
    <![CDATA[
        from Move as move
        where move.directionToMove = :direction
    ]]>
</query>
```

### Hibernate mapping

`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` still didn't work, so a custom `UserType` was necessary. The key was to correctly override `nullSafeSet` like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7614642/1090474 and [similar](https://anismiles.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/postgres-enum-with-hibernate/) [implementations](https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/issues/14) from the web.

```
@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (value == null) {
        st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
    }
    else {
        st.setObject(index, ((Enum) value).name(), Types.OTHER);
    }
}
```

### Detour

`implements ParameterizedType` wasn't cooperating:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: type is not parameterized: full.path.to.PGEnumUserType
```

so I wasn't able to annotate the enum property like this:

```
@Type(type = "full.path.to.PGEnumUserType",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "enumClass", value = "full.path.to.Move$Direction")
        }
)
```

Instead, I declared the class like so:

```
public class PGEnumUserType<E extends Enum<E>> implements UserType
```

with a constructor:

```
public PGEnumUserType(Class<E> enumClass) {
    this.enumClass = enumClass;
}
```

which, unfortunately, means any other enum property similarly mapped will need a class like this:

```
public class HibernateDirectionUserType extends PGEnumUserType<Direction> {
    public HibernateDirectionUserType() {
        super(Direction.class);
    }
}
```

### Annotation

Annotate the property and you're done.

```
@Column(name = "directiontomove", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "full.path.to.HibernateDirectionUserType")
private Direction directionToMove;
```

### Other notes

- `EnhancedUserType` and the three methods it wants implemented

  ```
  public String objectToSQLString(Object value)
  public String toXMLString(Object value)
  public String objectToSQLString(Object value)
  ```

  didn't make any difference I could see, so I stuck with `implements UserType`.
- Depending on how you're using the class, it might not be strictly necessary to make it postgres-specific by overriding `nullSafeGet` in the way the two linked solutions did.
- If you're willing to give up the postgres enum, you can make the column `text` and the original code will work without extra work.

Comment: So, what is the final code? I see a lot of excerpts but they don't gather in a solid solution in my mind. I need a solution instead of plenty of scattered improvements, a bunch of hyperlinks, that I don't want to follow, ideas and thoughts.

Answer (score 71):

You can simply get these types via Maven Central using the [Hypersistence Util](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils) dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Next, you need to annotate the field with the Hibernate `@Type` annotation, as illustrated in the following examples.

### Hibernate 6

If you're using Hibernate 6, map it like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public static class Post {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "post_status_info")
    @Type(PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
    private PostStatus status;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Here's [an example on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/9a397d939d3034c992e999a56eb8f893d1ce35e5/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/basic/PostgreSQLEnumTest.java#L36) that shows how it works with Hibernate 6.2.

### Hibernate 5

If you're using Hibernate 5, map it like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
@TypeDef(
    name = "pgsql_enum",
    typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
public static class Post {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "post_status_info")
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    private PostStatus status;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Here's [an example on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/9a397d939d3034c992e999a56eb8f893d1ce35e5/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/basic/PostgreSQLEnumTest.java#L121) that shows how it works with Hibernate 5.6.

This mapping assumes you have the `post_status_info` enum type in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TYPE post_status_info AS ENUM (
    'PENDING', 
    'APPROVED', 
    'SPAM'
)
```

That's it.

Comment: As you've said, works like a charm! Should have more upvotes.

Comment: That's the spirit!

Comment: Fantastic, should be accepted as best answer, works great! Upvoted

Comment: @VladMihalcea: I'm little bit confused about your library. Because I'm not really sure if your library now supports the Postgress enum types or not. So, IFFF I add the library to my project do I need the code or not? The reason for the confusion is that in your articles you explain how to set it up, but still leaves me doubts about functionality.

Comment: Yes, it does support it. This answer shows how to write a type that supports PostgreSQL Enum, and, it's exactly what the hibernate-types library dies in fact. Now, you can just use the type written by me or you can write it yourself. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @VladMihalcea: Somehow I didn't figure out how to use it properly with your package :-/ The other problem I'm facing is that for production we have Postgres but for testing we have h2. Is there a way to use them both for the same Java enum? Don't know if there is better place for a followup

Comment: I'd just like to point everyone who it trying to do this in a native query to this article: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-solve-the-postgresql-cast-operator-issue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/. I was looking for the way to cast this properly everywhere. Thanks @VladMihalcea

Comment: Any way to support hbm2ddl?

Comment: how about Hibernate 6 ?

Comment: org.hibernate.type.EnumType is deprecated and marked for removal.

Comment: I am getting Hibernate validation errors reported, although it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Hibernate < 6.3 version**

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::yours_enum_type")
private YoursEnumType enumType;
```

**Hibernate 6.3**

Looks like it's supported out of the box since 6.3.0.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16125

Answer (score 1):

As said in [8.7.3. Type Safety of Postgres Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-enum.html):

> If you really need to do something like that, you can either write a custom operator or add explicit casts to your query:

so if you want a quick and simple workaround, do like this:

```
<query name="getAllMoves">
<![CDATA[
    select move from Move move
    where cast(directiontomove as text) = cast(:directionToMove as text)
]]>
</query>
```

Unfortunately, [you can't do it simply with two colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475876/using-hibernate-query-colon-gets-treated-as-parameter-escaping-colon):

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off saying I was able to do this using Hibernate 4.3.x and Postgres 9.x.

I based my solution off something similar to what you did.  I believe if you combine

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.EnumType",
parameters = {
        @Parameter(name  = "enumClass", value = "full.path.to.Move$Direction"),
        @Parameter(name = "type", value = "12"),
        @Parameter(name = "useNamed", value = "true")
})
```

and this

```
@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
  if (value == null) {
    st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
  }
  else {
    st.setObject(index, ((Enum) value).name(), Types.OTHER);
  }
}
```

You should be able to get something along the lines of this, without having to make either above change.

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.EnumType",
parameters = {
        @Parameter(name  = "enumClass", value = "full.path.to.Move$Direction"),
        @Parameter(name = "type", value = "1111"),
        @Parameter(name = "useNamed", value = "true")
})
```

I believe that this works since you're essentially telling Hibernate to map the enum to a type of other (`Types.OTHER == 1111`).  It may be a slightly brittle solution since the value of `Types.OTHER` could change.  However, this would provide significantly less code overall.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach with a persistence converter:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;

@Column(name = "direction", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = DirectionConverter.class)
private Direction directionToMove;
```

This is a converter definition:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class DirectionConverter implements AttributeConverter<Direction, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Direction direction) {
        return direction.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Direction convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return Diretion.valueOf(string);
    }
}
```

It does not resolve mapping to psql enum type, but it can simulate @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) or @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) in a good way.

For ordinal use direction.ordinal() and Direction.values()[number].